# Why won't my JQuery .animate() work?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

```
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});


</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".allSideBars").delay(3000).animate({ marginLeft: "-100%"}, 700);
    });
</script>

</head>
```

Here's the code in my  section on the offending page. The animation part works fine on my homepage, when I link to the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
```

So is it just due to my script linking? If so, how can I make this work on my other page? All I want to do is have this animation fire on all my pages like it does on the homepage.

Comment: you may have to include jquery migration plugin also, since you are using jquery 1.9.0 - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js

Comment: Check your script paths.  The top script looks for jquery in a lib folder, whereas the lower script looks for jquery in an assets folder.  Make sure your script paths are correct.

Comment: are you using both jquery 1.5&1.9 in same page?

Comment: My script paths are ok, the reason they are different is because they link to different scripts on different pages, I was only illustrating the difference. And I'll look into JQuery migration, never heard of it before :D, I'm not using the two scripts on the same page because if I use 1.5, it stops my fancybox from working, so I don't seem to be able to do that

Comment: I tried to use Jquery migrate to no effect, it didn't cure the problem :(

Comment: @user2021641 I've setup an instance of your code in its simplest form here: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/XL4Hy/, as you can see it works (at least for me it does across IE,FF and Chrome). I think this might be related to your css in the sub pages.

Answer (score 0):

Http is a stateless protocol so if you want to have a script working on multiple pages, you have to include it on each page.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the speedy response, however I tried to do this but it stopped the fancybox from working! Is there any other solution?

Comment: if it stops working, it may mean you have other script errors on the page, check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: ok, so I linked both the scripts, ran the webpage and it came up with this "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain" errors, can you recommend a way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To test your jquery use somethink like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('it works!');
    });
</script>
```

And is you see this message in your console (open Chrome press F12 and click on console tab) its work!